# Write a sum of independent values in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, distributed-computing

I have a function, say `foo()` that returns an `int` value, and I have to pass to different values to this function to obtaion two different values that have to be summed up, eg.

```
result = foo(2) + foo(37)
```

and I would like to make those `foo(2)` and `foo(37)` to be calculated in parallel (at the same time). It may help to have two versions of `foo`, one that uses a for loop and another one recursive. I am quite new to Julia and parallel programming but would like to get this problem going so that I can keep it up until I can build it as a web app with Genie.jl. Also, any resources to learn about parallel programming with Julia besides its docs will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use processes for the parallelisation you can use the "distributed for" loop:

8.2.3. Aggregate results

The second situation is when you want to perform a small operation on each of the items but you also want to perform an “aggregation function” at the end to retrieve a scalar value (or an array if the input is a matrix).
In these cases, you can use the **`@distributed`** (aggregationFunction) for construct.

As an example, you run in parallel a division by 2 and then use the sum as the aggregation function (assume three working processes are available):

```
function f(n)
  s = 0.0
  for i = 1:n
    s += i/2
  end
  return s
end

function pf(n)
  s = @distributed (+) for i = 1:n # aggregate using sum on variable s
    i/2
    # last element of for cycle is used by the aggregator
  end
  return s
end

@benchmark f(10000000) # median time:    11.478 ms
@benchmark pf(10000000) # median time:    4.458 ms
```

(From [Julia Quick Syntax Reference](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484251898))

Alternatively you can use threads. Julia already have multi-threads, but Julia 1.3 (due in few days/weeks, in rc4 at time of writing) will introduce a comprehensive thread API.

Comment: So it will not be "experimental" anymore as they make clear everywhere in their docs?